# How to use dynamic values in domain filter?

Tags: odoo

The following is my line of code and is working,

```
'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsible', track_visibility='onchange', domain="[('emp_department_id', '=', 10)]"),
```

Now i want replace that employee department id and that should be the value returned by a function,

say something similar to this

```
def test():
     return department id of the login users

'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsible', track_visibility='onchange', domain="[('emp_department_id', '=', self.test())]"),
```

I know the above statement is not valid since the whole thing is a dict and domain is one of the key in the dict and its value is string. I want this concept to be done somehow.

I am even ok for some crooked ideas. Thanks for your time.